# how to show nested JSON in angular 2?

Tags: json, angular

I am new to angular 2. i am facing problem in showing nested JSON in my html view. I have following json.

```
{
    "totalItems": 347,
    "totalPages": 35,
    "results": [
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 128GB - Gold (AT&T)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRP2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5580428",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5580/5580428_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5580428/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055804286",
            "SNR_Price": "699.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 128GB - Gold (Sprint)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRP2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5580908",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5580/5580908_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5580908/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055809083",
            "SNR_Price": "699.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 128GB - Gold (Verizon)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRP2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5581618",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5581/5581618_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5581618/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055816180",
            "SNR_Price": "699.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 128GB - Silver (AT&T)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRM2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5580429",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5580/5580429_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5580429/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055804293",
            "SNR_Price": "699.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 128GB - Silver (Sprint)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRM2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5580909",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5580/5580909_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5580909/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055809090",
            "SNR_Price": "699.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 128GB - Silver (Verizon)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRM2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5581619",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5581/5581619_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5581619/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055816197",
            "SNR_Price": "699.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 128GB - Space Gray (AT&T)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRL2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5580426",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5580/5580426_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5580426/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055804262",
            "SNR_Price": "699.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 16GB - Space Gray (Sprint)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MKRC2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 Series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE&#185; and Wi-Fi. Long battery life.&#178; And iOS 9 and iCloud. All in a smooth continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5440400",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5440/5440400_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5440400/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400054404005",
            "SNR_Price": "549.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 32GB - Gold (AT&T)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MN1K2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5580395",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5580/5580395_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5580395/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055803951",
            "SNR_Price": "599.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Apple - iPhone 6s 32GB - Gold (Sprint)",
            "SNR_Brand": "Apple",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "MN1K2LL/A",
            "SNR_Description": "A 4.7-inch Retina HD display with 3D Touch. 7000 series aluminum and stronger cover glass. An A9 chip with 64-bit desktop-class architecture. All new 12MP iSight camera with Live Photos. Touch ID. Faster LTE and Wi-Fi. Long battery life and iOS 10 and iCloud. All in a smooth, continuous unibody design.",
            "SNR_SKU": "BB5580737",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5580/5580737_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5580737/pdp",
            "SNR_UPC": "400055807379",
            "SNR_Price": "599.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i am receiving this in **GetAllMobile** array.
**my service look like this**.

```
this.httpService.getAllMobiles().subscribe(
    data => {
      const myArray = [];


      for (let key in data) {
        myArray.push(data[key]);
        this.GetAllMobile.push(data[key])

      }
      console.log(this.GetAllMobile)
    }, () => this.loading = false
  );
```

and what i have tried this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of GetAllMobile">
    <h2>
        Total {{item.totalItems}} {{item.totalPages}} AMAD
    </h2>
</div>
```

but it does not showing me simple **totalItems and Total pages**. and to show results i am trying this.

```
<div *ngFor="let test of GetAllMobile">
    <div *ngFor="let x of test.results">
  <p>
      {{x.SNR_Title}}
  </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

it is also showing me nothing.

can anybody give me hint or code that how can i show it in angular 2 with typescript.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `GetAllMobile` is an array, not an object. To make this work as expected, you will have to work with an object (as data is also an object) and then just iterate over the results.

Comment: Okay.. let me try.. i will be back in short time.

Comment: Is there any method in which i can convert this array into object form

Comment: Well... data already is an object. If you want to make sure it contains only the keys you specify, you can just write the values into your `GetAllMobile`:
`this.GetAllMobile.totalItems = data.totalItems....` if you want to check if the key exists, you can use `data.hasOwnProperty` to validate. Otherwise just assign the whole data object as @JBNizet points out.

Comment: You're really overthinking this. You already receive an object. Just store that object, as is (let's call it page, since it represents a page of mobile phones) in your component. Then display it with `<h2># of items: {{page.totalItems}} - # of pages: {{page.totalPages}}</h2><div *ngFor="let mobile in page.results">{{ mobile.SNR_Title } ...</div>`

Comment: i added following steps @JBNizet. i have declare getMobile as Object and give getMobile=GetAllMobile . now i am able to access totalItems as {{getMobile[0]}} and total pages as {{getMobile[1]}}. all is well till this step. but loop is not working as <div *ngFor="let mobile of GetMobile.results">{{ mobile.SNR_Title }</div> can you have any idea about this?

Comment: Don with it.<div *ngFor="let mobile of GetMobile[2]">
    <h2>{{ mobile.SNR_Title}}</h2>
   </div>

Comment: Why don't you just read my comment. You have the right structure from the start, and transforming it into an array of mixed unrelated stuff for no reason, just making the code longer, more cryptic, and less efficient, for not reason at all.

Comment: OK.. i am reading your comment more carefully and implementing like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If GetAllMobile is an array, then the JSON you posted is an object in GetAllMobile and can be displayed following way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of GetAllMobile">
  <h2>
      Total {{item.totalItems}} {{item.totalPages}} AMAD
  </h2>

  <div *ngFor="let x of item.results">
    <p>
        {{x.SNR_Title}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you set the JSON to GetAllMobile, then it becomes an object, and values become directly accessible:

```
<div>
  <h2>
      Total {{GetAllMobileObject.totalItems}} {{GetAllMobileObject.totalPages}} AMAD
  </h2>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let x of GetAllMobileObject.results">
    <p>
        {{x.SNR_Title}}
    </p>
</div>
```

I have created this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rtBxU7xqR0pPng6zAiSN?p=preview) for both cases using your code example. Hope this helps.